# Oracle SQL Query Group By

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have the table here named `percentage`, it contains policy number, priority and percentage.

[image]

I need to create an sql query that would aggregate these percentage for each policy. The problem is I have a priority column that needs to be followed. Meaning, before you apply the next percentage you need to deduct first the previous percentage. And you have to repeat that until the last percentage. I have tried to research on google but to no avail. Hope you guys can help me on this.

You may access the table here: https://dbfiddle.uk/r8rhgjhF

Comment: provide some sample code that you tried until now.

Comment: Im actually stuck to this, SELECT POLICY, SUM ( PERCENTAGE ) PERCENTAGE FROM PERCENTAGE GROUP BY POLICY. Im new to SQL so Im not really sure what's next.

Comment: Create a https://dbfiddle.uk/7Jxju0AY with your tables and sample data and update your post with the url

Comment: table and sample data is now uploaded >> https://dbfiddle.uk/r8rhgjhF

Comment: at first sight, it seems to be a good use case for the MODEL clause, but you should write correctly your formula before starting to implement it: what you show in column R is not "previous value + (1 - previous value) x current value" but "previous value + (1 - previous value) x current percentage"

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from percentage
model return updated rows
partition by (policy)
dimension by (priority p)
measures ( 1 q , percentage pc)
rules (
    q[p] = NVL(q[cv()-1] + (1-q[cv()-1]) * pc[cv()],pc[cv()])
)
;
```

will give you

```
55188   1   0,3     0,3
55188   2   0,65    0,5
55166   1   0,65    0,65
55166   2   0,811   0,46
55166   3   0,8488  0,2
```

selecting the rows where priority is the max per policy can be done with analytic function.

```
select policy, p, q from (
    select row_number() over(partition by policy order by p desc) as rn, policy, p, q from (
        select policy, p, q from percentage
        model return updated rows
        partition by (policy)
        dimension by (priority p)
        measures ( 1 q , percentage pc)
        rules (
            q[p] = NVL(q[cv()-1] + (1-q[cv()-1]) * pc[cv()],pc[cv()])
        )
    ) d
)
where rn = 1
;
```